# Sending email through SharePoint designer 2013 workflow

Tags: sharepoint, project-management, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, ms-project-server-2016

I'm trying to send an email to a person who submitted a new project request as part of a SharePoint Designer workflow using a project detail page (PDP) in Microsoft Project Server 2016.

Email recipient will be different in each time since different people can submit a project request and the workflow needs to determine the email address of the person who submitted the request and emails the person.

I cannot find a way to set up the email recipient in SharePoint Designer 2013 to accomplish this task.

I found the following URL on this subject http://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/how-to-send-an-email-using-workflow-when-items-are-created-or-updated-in-sharepoint/.

However, the step 6 on this page does not provide enough details on how to set up the recipient email automatically in the SharePoint Designer 2013 workflow.

Is this possible? Can you please help?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Have you selected the "directory book" to the right of the To: field? If so, what options do you see available?

Comment: Yes, I did. I do not see the "User who created current item" option in the "Select Users" dialog box because "Current Item" is not available for me to select. I wonder if this is due to I'm using Project Server 2016 workflow type instead of regular SharePoint workflow type.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty straight forward

In recipient field To: click on directory book then select "Workflow lookup for user" in menu, then in Data source give **Workflow context** and select Initiator. It will be the user who initiated the workflow i.e added in new request OR if the workflow is set to run on Item Edit as well then "Initiator" can also contain the user who modified.

[see snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LzpWs.png)

BUT since **Current Item** is also available in menu you can always select "Created by" "Modified by" fields in recipient list against label **To:**